# Undesired output with tf.reduce_sum()

Tags: pandas, numpy, tensorflow, tensorboard

Using tensorflow reduce_sum but getting undesired output. 
I am trying to calculate the below thing:

```
x = tf.constant([[1,1,1],[1,1,1]])
tf.reduce_sum(x,0)



expected output = [2, 2, 2]

actual output = <tf.Tensor 'Sum:0' shape=() dtype=int32>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to display, you need to be in a session and use `eval()`

```
import tensorflow as tf
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

x = tf.constant([[1,1,1],[1,1,1]])
tf.reduce_sum(x,0).eval()
```